# How to download files on server to local machine using JSP

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat

Lot of research and hard work but still not getting the solution.I have one web application which is hosted on company server on which I am running my tomcat and web application inside tomcat. I am not being able to download the files located on server within specific folder.

JSP code here below

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text\html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1" import="java.io.File,java.io.IOException,java.util.*,java.io.*,java.text.SimpleDateFormat"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text\html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<script type="text/javascript">
function downloadPDF(_var)
   {
    var docLocation = "path same as given below of variable 'filename'"+_var;
    window.open(docLocation,"resizeable,scrollbar");           
   }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<%
     String filename = "path of folder on server outside of tomcat directory(i.e outside of project foler)";
     File f = new File(filename); // current directory
     File[] files = f.listFiles();  
     for (File file : files) { 
       if (file.isDirectory()) {  
          //System.out.print("directory:");
       } else {
 %>
 <a href="#" target="" onclick="downloadPDF('<%=file.getName()%>')"><br><%= file.getName()+"_"+currentDate%></a>
 <%  
    } 
 } 
 %>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: My application is running on different server and user trying to download file from his local machine....

Comment: _I am not being able to download_ - what does it mean? What happens, when you click the download link?

Comment: Thanks for reply @JozefChocholacek...i got it worked from other way using servlet...anyways...but i want to access server file through jsp only...when anchor tag is gets clicked..file should be downloaded..which is not happening...i get error 'Failed to load the resources'

Comment: As per my understanding, path written in java code inside expression tag that is being accessed and all list of all files inside that folder gets recognized...But when downloadPDF() function gets called which is gonna load on browser(i.e) on my local machine will search file on local instead of searching on given path in 'docLocation' variable.....Put opinions on this point...